# Windows Registry placeholders %1, %L, %*,

Tags: windows, windows-registry, placeholder

I've noticed that in the registry some placeholders are used to replace text strings when calling OS sub-systems...

%1 is easy to understand...

My question is what %L means ?
Are there more placeholders ? and what their meaning ?
Why %* doesn't work in registry ?